# how to set up minutes after 12am to 12:30am

Tags: javascript

*How to set up hour for 12:30am* it only works up until 11:30pm using hour

- List item
  *How to set up hour for 12:30am* it only works up until 11:30pm using hour <=22 | minutes <= 30 but as soon as i try doing 12am and up in minutes no show

  ```js
      var img2 = new Image();
      var now2 = new Date();
    

    var checkTime2 = function() {

    var timeDivBorder2 = document.getElementById('timeBorder2');
    var timeDiv2 = document.getElementById('timeDiv2');
    var timeDivBorderTaco2 = document.getElementById('timeBorderTaco2');
    var timeDivTaco2 = document.getElementById('timeDivTaco2');
    var timeDivBorderDine2 = document.getElementById('timeBorderDine2');
    var timeDivDine2 = document.getElementById('timeDivDine2');
    var timeDivBorderBreakfast2 = document.getElementById('timeBorderBreakfast2');
    var timeDivBreakfast2 = document.getElementById('timeDivBreakfast2');
    


    var today = weekday[now2.getDay()];
    var dayOfWeek = now2.getDay();
    var hour = now2.getHours();
    var minutes = now2.getMinutes();

    //add AM or PM
    var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";


    // add 0 to one digit minutes
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes
    };

    if ((dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 0 ) && hour >= 6 && hour <= 21) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
   timeDivBorder2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDiv2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
      timeDiv2.className = 'open';
   timeDivBorderTaco2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDivTaco2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
   timeDivTaco2.className = 'open';
   timeDivBorderDine2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDivDine2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
   timeDivDine2.className = 'open';
   timeDivBorderBreakfast2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDivBreakfast2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
   timeDivBreakfast2.className = 'open';
   img2.src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOn.gif';
    }

    else if ((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 9 && hour <= 23) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
   timeDivBorder2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDiv2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
      timeDiv2.className = 'open';
   timeDivBorderTaco2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDivTaco2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
   timeDivTaco2.className = 'open';
   timeDivBorderDine2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDivDine2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
   timeDivDine2.className = 'open';
   timeDivBorderBreakfast2.className = 'openGreen';
   timeDivBreakfast2.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>';
   timeDivBreakfast2.className = 'open';
   img2.src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOn.gif';
    }

    else {
      if (hour == 0 || hour > 8) {
        hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
      }
   timeDivBorder2.className = 'closedRed';
   timeDiv2.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>' ;
      timeDiv2.className = 'closed';
   timeDivBorderTaco2.className = 'closedRed';
   timeDivTaco2.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>' ;
      timeDivTaco2.className = 'closed';
   timeDivBorderDine2.className = 'closedRed';
   timeDivDine2.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>' ;
      timeDivDine2.className = 'closed';
   timeDivBorderBreakfast2.className = 'closedRed';
   timeDivBreakfast2.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br><center><img style="width:100%;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+img2.src+'" /></center>' ;
      timeDivBreakfast2.className = 'closed';
   img2.src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOff.png';
    }
  };

  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";
  var currentDay2 = weekday[now2.getDay()];
  var currentDayID2 = "#" + currentDay2; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
  $(currentDayID2).toggleClass("today"); //hightlights today in the view hours modal popup'

  setInterval(checkTime2, 1000);
  checkTime2();
  ```

  ```css
  /*timee*/

  .timebox{
   position:fixed;
   display:block;
   padding:0px;
   top:10px;
   right:10px;
   z-index:1;
  }

  .open {
    color: #27ae60;

  }

  .openGreen {
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #3DFF01;
    animation: Open 1s infinite;
  }
  @keyframes Open {
   50%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #30cc00;}
  }

  .closed {

    color: rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.85);

  }

  .closedRed {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #FF0101;
  animation: close 1s infinite;
  }
  @keyframes close {
   50%{box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #FF0101;}
  }

  [id^="timeBorder"] {
   border-radius:20px;
   margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
   bottom:5px;
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   padding:0px;
      width:185px;
   height:185px;
  }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }

  /*
   #timeDiv1, #timeDiv2, #timeDiv3,
   #timeDiv4, #timeDiv5, #timeDiv6,
   #timeDiv7, #timeDiv8, #timeDiv9,
   #timeDiv10, #timeDiv11, #timeDiv12,
   #timeDiv13, #timeDiv14, #timeDiv15,
   #timeDiv16, #timeDiv17, #timeDiv18,
   #timeDiv19, #timeDiv20, #timeDiv21,
   #timeDiv22, #timeDiv23, #timeDiv24,
   #timeDiv25, #timeDiv26, #timeDiv27,
   #timeDiv28, #timeDiv29, #timeDiv30,
   #timeDiv31, #timeDiv32, #timeDiv33,
   #timeDiv34, #timeDiv35, #timeDiv36,
   #timeDiv37, #timeDiv38, #timeDiv39,
   #timeDiv40, #timeDiv41,
   
   #timeDivTaco2,
   
    #timeDivDine2,
   
   #timeDivBreakfast2*/
   [id ^="timeDiv"]
   {
    font-size: .9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    position:static;
    width:185px;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
   /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;*/
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }

   /*
   .viewOpen1, .viewOpen2, .viewOpen3,
   .viewOpen4, .viewOpen5, .viewOpen6,
   .viewOpen7, .viewOpen8, .viewOpen9,
   .viewOpen10, .viewOpen11, .viewOpen12,
   .viewOpen13, .viewOpen14, .viewOpen15,
   .viewOpen16, .viewOpen17, .viewOpen18,
   .viewOpen19, .viewOpen20, .viewOpen21,
   .viewOpen22, .viewOpen23, .viewOpen24,
   .viewOpen25, .viewOpen26, .viewOpen27,
   .viewOpen28, .viewOpen29, .viewOpen30,
   .viewOpen31, .viewOpen32, .viewOpen33,
   .viewOpen34, .viewOpen35, .viewOpen36,
   .viewOpen37, .viewOpen38, .viewOpen39,
   .viewOpen40, .viewOpen41,
   
   .viewOpenTaco2,
   
   .viewOpenDine2,
   
   .viewOpenBreakfast2*/
   
  [class^="viewOpen"]
   {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:block;
    border: 2px solid rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.7);
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.8);
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:160px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:blue solid 1px;
    position:static;

  }

  /*
   .viewOpen1 i, .viewOpen2 i, .viewOpen3 i,
   .viewOpen4 i, .viewOpen5 i, .viewOpen6 i,
   .viewOpen7 i, .viewOpen8 i, .viewOpen9 i,
   .viewOpen10 i, .viewOpen11 i, .viewOpen12 i,
   .viewOpen13 i, .viewOpen14 i, .viewOpen15 i,
   .viewOpen16 i, .viewOpen17 i, .viewOpen18 i,
   .viewOpen19 i, .viewOpen20 i, .viewOpen21 i,
   .viewOpen22 i, .viewOpen23 i, .viewOpen24 i,
   .viewOpen25 i, .viewOpen26 i, .viewOpen27 i,
   .viewOpen28 i, .viewOpen29 i, .viewOpen30 i,
   .viewOpen31 i, .viewOpen32 i, .viewOpen33 i,
   .viewOpen34 i, .viewOpen35 i, .viewOpen36 i,
   .viewOpen37 i, .viewOpen38 i, .viewOpen39 i,
   .viewOpen40 i, .viewOpen41 i,
   
   .viewOpenTaco2 i,
   
   .viewOpenDine2 i,
   
   .viewOpenBreakfast2 i*/
   [class^="viewOpen"] i
   {
    color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.8);
  }





  .dateTime  {
    max-width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .day {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }

  .time {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right
  }

  .today {
    color: rgb(200, 85, 39);
    font-weight: 600;
  }


  /*
  @media all and (max-height: 420px) {
    #timeDiv1, .viewOpen1,
    #timeDiv6, .viewOpen6,
    #timeDiv31, .viewOpen31,
    #timeDiv32, .viewOpen32,
    #timeDiv33, .viewOpen33
    {
      top: 60%;
    }
  }
   view hours modal */

  @keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
   /*
   .modal-overlay1, .modal-overlay2, .modal-overlay3,
   .modal-overlay4, .modal-overlay5, .modal-overlay6,
   .modal-overlay7, .modal-overlay8, .modal-overlay9,
   .modal-overlay10, .modal-overlay11, .modal-overlay12,
   .modal-overlay13, .modal-overlay14, .modal-overlay15,
   .modal-overlay16, .modal-overlay17, .modal-overlay18,
   .modal-overlay19, .modal-overlay20, .modal-overlay21,
   .modal-overlay22, .modal-overlay23, .modal-overlay24,
   .modal-overlay25, .modal-overlay26, .modal-overlay27,
   .modal-overlay28, .modal-overlay29, .modal-overlay30,
   .modal-overlay31, .modal-overlay32, .modal-overlay33,
   .modal-overlay34, .modal-overlay35, .modal-overlay36,
   .modal-overlay37, .modal-overlay38, .modal-overlay39,
   .modal-overlay40, .modal-overlay41,
   
   .modal-overlayTaco2,
   
   .modal-overlayDine2,
   
   .modal-overlayBreakfast2
   */
  [class ^= "modal-overlay"]
   {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(173, 173, 173, .3);
    display: none;
  }
  /*
   #modal-state1, #modal-state2, #modal-state3,
   #modal-state4, #modal-state5, #modal-state6,
   #modal-state7, #modal-state8, #modal-state9,
   #modal-state10, #modal-state11, #modal-state12,
   #modal-state13, #modal-state14, #modal-state15,
   #modal-state16, #modal-state17, #modal-state18,
   #modal-state19, #modal-state20, #modal-state21,
   #modal-state22, #modal-state23, #modal-state24,
   #modal-state25, #modal-state26, #modal-state27,
   #modal-state28, #modal-state29, #modal-state30,
   #modal-state31, #modal-state32, #modal-state33,
   #modal-state34, #modal-state35, #modal-state36,
   #modal-state37, #modal-state38, #modal-state39,
   #modal-state40, #modal-state41,
   
   #modal-stateTaco2,
   
   #modal-stateDine2,

   #modal-stateBreakfast2*/
   [id^="modal-state"]
   {
    display: none;
  }
  /*
   #modal-state1:checked + .modal-overlay1, #modal-state2:checked + .modal-overlay2, #modal-state3:checked + .modal-overlay3,
   #modal-state4:checked + .modal-overlay4, #modal-state5:checked + .modal-overlay5, #modal-state6:checked + .modal-overlay6,
   #modal-state7:checked + .modal-overlay7, #modal-state8:checked + .modal-overlay8, #modal-state9:checked + .modal-overlay9,
   #modal-state10:checked + .modal-overlay10, #modal-state11:checked + .modal-overlay11, #modal-state12:checked + .modal-overlay12,
   #modal-state13:checked + .modal-overlay13, #modal-state14:checked + .modal-overlay14, #modal-state15:checked + .modal-overlay15,
   #modal-state16:checked + .modal-overlay16, #modal-state17:checked + .modal-overlay17, #modal-state18:checked + .modal-overlay18,
   #modal-state19:checked + .modal-overlay19, #modal-state20:checked + .modal-overlay20, #modal-state21:checked + .modal-overlay21,
   #modal-state22:checked + .modal-overlay22, #modal-state23:checked + .modal-overlay23, #modal-state24:checked + .modal-overlay24,
   #modal-state25:checked + .modal-overlay25, #modal-state26:checked + .modal-overlay26, #modal-state27:checked + .modal-overlay27,
   #modal-state28:checked + .modal-overlay28, #modal-state29:checked + .modal-overlay29, #modal-state30:checked + .modal-overlay30,
   #modal-state31:checked + .modal-overlay31, #modal-state32:checked + .modal-overlay32, #modal-state33:checked + .modal-overlay33,
   #modal-state34:checked + .modal-overlay34, #modal-state35:checked + .modal-overlay35, #modal-state36:checked + .modal-overlay36,
   #modal-state37:checked + .modal-overlay37, #modal-state38:checked + .modal-overlay38, #modal-state39:checked + .modal-overlay39,
   #modal-state40:checked + .modal-overlay40, #modal-state41:checked + .modal-overlay41,

   
   #modal-stateTaco2:checked + .modal-overlayTaco2,
   
   #modal-stateDine2:checked + .modal-overlayDine2,
   
   #modal-stateBreakfast2:checked + .modal-overlayBreakfast2
   */
   
   [id^="modal-state"]:checked + [class^="modal-overlay"]
   {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade-in .4s;
    display: block;
  }
  /*
   .modaltime1, .modaltime2, .modaltime3, .modaltime4,
   .modaltime5, .modaltime6, .modaltime7, .modaltime8,
   .modaltime9, .modaltime10, .modaltime11, .modaltime12,
   .modaltime13, .modaltime14, .modaltime15, .modaltime16,
   .modaltime17, .modaltime18, .modaltime19, .modaltime20,
   .modaltime21, .modaltime22, .modaltime23, .modaltime24,
   .modaltime25, .modaltime26, .modaltime27, .modaltime28,
   .modaltime29, .modaltime30, .modaltime31, .modaltime32,
   .modaltime33, .modaltime34, .modaltime35, .modaltime36,
   .modaltime37, .modaltime38, .modaltime39, .modaltime40,
   .modaltime41*/

   [class^= "modaltime"] 
   {
    position:fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    background: #fff;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 400px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    border:red solid 1px;
  }
  /*
   .modaltime1 h2, .modaltime2 h2, .modaltime3 h2, .modaltime4 h2,
   .modaltime5 h2, .modaltime6 h2, .modaltime7 h2, .modaltime8 h2,
   .modaltime9 h2, .modaltime10 h2, .modaltime11 h2, .modaltime12 h2,
   .modaltime13 h2, .modaltime14 h2, .modaltime15 h2, .modaltime16 h2,
   .modaltime17 h2, .modaltime18 h2, .modaltime19 h2, .modaltime20 h2,
   .modaltime21 h2, .modaltime22 h2, .modaltime23 h2, .modaltime24 h2,
   .modaltime25 h2, .modaltime26 h2, .modaltime27 h2, .modaltime28 h2,
   .modaltime29 h2, .modaltime30 h2, .modaltime31 h2, .modaltime32 h2,
   .modaltime33 h2, .modaltime34 h2, .modaltime35 h2, .modaltime36 h2,
   .modaltime37 h2, .modaltime38 h2, .modaltime39 h2, .modaltime40 h2,
   .modaltime41 h2 */

   [class^= "modaltime"] h2 
   {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dce0d8;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  @media all and (max-width: 470px) {
    .modaltime1, .modaltime6, .modaltime31, .modaltime32, .modaltime33 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    
    .modaltime1 h2, .modaltime6 h2, .modaltime31 h2,.modaltime32 h2,.modaltime33 h2{
      font-size: 20px;
    }

  }

  /*
   #modal-state1:checked + .modal-overlay1 .modaltime1, #modal-state2:checked + .modal-overlay2 .modaltime2, #modal-state3:checked + .modal-overlay3 .modaltime3,
   #modal-state4:checked + .modal-overlay4 .modaltime4, #modal-state5:checked + .modal-overlay5 .modaltime5, #modal-state6:checked + .modal-overlay6 .modaltime6,
   #modal-state7:checked + .modal-overlay7 .modaltime7, #modal-state8:checked + .modal-overlay8 .modaltime7, #modal-state9:checked + .modal-overlay9 .modaltime9,
   #modal-state10:checked + .modal-overlay10 .modaltime10, #modal-state11:checked + .modal-overlay11 .modaltime11, #modal-state12:checked + .modal-overlay12 .modaltime12,
   #modal-state13:checked + .modal-overlay13 .modaltime13, #modal-state14:checked + .modal-overlay14 .modaltime14, #modal-state15:checked + .modal-overlay15 .modaltime15,
   #modal-state16:checked + .modal-overlay16 .modaltime16, #modal-state17:checked + .modal-overlay17 .modaltime17, #modal-state18:checked + .modal-overlay18 .modaltime18,
   #modal-state19:checked + .modal-overlay19 .modaltime19, #modal-state20:checked + .modal-overlay20 .modaltime20, #modal-state21:checked + .modal-overlay21 .modaltime21,
   #modal-state22:checked + .modal-overlay22 .modaltime22, #modal-state23:checked + .modal-overlay23 .modaltime23, #modal-state24:checked + .modal-overlay24 .modaltime24,
   #modal-state25:checked + .modal-overlay25 .modaltime25, #modal-state26:checked + .modal-overlay26 .modaltime29, #modal-state27:checked + .modal-overlay27 .modaltime27,
   #modal-state28:checked + .modal-overlay28 .modaltime28, #modal-state29:checked + .modal-overlay29 .modaltime29, #modal-state30:checked + .modal-overlay30 .modaltime30,
   #modal-state31:checked + .modal-overlay31 .modaltime31, #modal-state32:checked + .modal-overlay32 .modaltime32, #modal-state33:checked + .modal-overlay33 .modaltime33,
   #modal-state34:checked + .modal-overlay34 .modaltime34, #modal-state35:checked + .modal-overlay35 .modaltime35, #modal-state36:checked + .modal-overlay36 .modaltime36,
   #modal-state37:checked + .modal-overlay37 .modaltime37, #modal-state38:checked + .modal-overlay38 .modaltime38, #modal-state39:checked + .modal-overlay39 .modaltime39,
   #modal-state40:checked + .modal-overlay40 .modaltime40, #modal-state41:checked + .modal-overlay41 .modaltime41,
   
   #modal-stateTaco2:checked + .modal-overlayTaco2 .modaltime2,
   #modal-stateDine2:checked + .modal-overlayDine2 .modaltime2,
   #modal-stateBreakfast2:checked + .modal-overlayBreakfast2 .modaltime2
  */
  [id^= "modal-state"]:checked + [class^= "modal-overlay"] [class^= "modaltime"]
  {
    top: 20%;
  }

  /*
   .modal-overlay-close1, .modal-overlay-close2, .modal-overlay-close3, .modal-overlay-close4,
   .modal-overlay-close5, .modal-overlay-close6, .modal-overlay-close7, .modal-overlay-close8,
   .modal-overlay-close9, .modal-overlay-close10, .modal-overlay-close11, .modal-overlay-close12,
   .modal-overlay-close13, .modal-overlay-close14, .modal-overlay-close15, .modal-overlay-close16,
   .modal-overlay-close17, .modal-overlay-close18, .modal-overlay-close19, .modal-overlay-close20,
   .modal-overlay-close21, .modal-overlay-close22, .modal-overlay-close23, .modal-overlay-close24,
   .modal-overlay-close25, .modal-overlay-close26, .modal-overlay-close27, .modal-overlay-close28,
   .modal-overlay-close29, .modal-overlay-close30, .modal-overlay-close31, .modal-overlay-close32,
   .modal-overlay-close33, .modal-overlay-close34, .modal-overlay-close35, .modal-overlay-close36,
   .modal-overlay-close37, .modal-overlay-close38, .modal-overlay-close39, .modal-overlay-close40,
   .modal-overlay-close41,
   
   .modal-overlay-closeTaco2,
   .modal-overlay-closeDine2,
   .modal-overlay-closeBreakfast2*/

   [class^="modal-overlay-close"] 
   {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display:block;
  }
  /*
   .button-close1, .button-close2, .button-close3, .button-close4,
   .button-close5, .button-close6, .button-close7, .button-close8,
   .button-close9, .button-close10, .button-close11, .button-close12,
   .button-close13, .button-close14, .button-close15, .button-close16,
   .button-close17, .button-close18, .button-close19, .button-close20,
   .button-close21, .button-close22, .button-close23, .button-close24,
   .button-close25, .button-close26, .button-close27, .button-close28,
   .button-close29, .button-close30, .button-close31, .button-close32,
   .button-close33, .button-close34, .button-close35, .button-close36,
   .button-close37, .button-close38, .button-close39, .button-close40,
   .button-close41,
   
   .button-closeTaco2,
   .button-closeDine2,
   .button-closeBreakfast2*/
   [class^="button-close"]
   {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    background: #464646;
    padding: 0px 7px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer
  }
  /*time end*/
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="timebox"  >
  <div id="timeDiv2"></div>
  <label class="viewOpen2" for="modal-state2">View Hours&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="modal-state2" id="modal-state2">
  <div class="modal-overlay2">
  <label for="modal-state2" class="modal-overlay-close2"></label>

  <div class="modaltime2">
  <label class="button-close2" for="modal-state2"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></label>
  <h2>We're Open At These Times</h2>
  <div id="Monday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Monday</div>
  <div class="time">6am - 10pm</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="Tuesday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="time">6am - 10pm</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="Wednesday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="time">6am - 10pm</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="Thursday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Thursday</div>
  <div class="time">6am - 10pm</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="Friday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Friday</div>
  <div class="time">6am - 11pm</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="Saturday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Saturday</div>
  <div class="time">6am - 11pm</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="Sunday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Sunday</div>
  <div class="time">6am - 10pm</div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Do you realize that 12:30AM is actually 0:30 (in 24-hour format)?

Comment: The getHours() method returns the hour (from 0 to 23) of the specified date and time. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp          
 && hour >= 6 && hour <= 23 | minutes <= 30 should say 12:30am but it closes at 12am

Comment: The getHours() method returns the hour (from 0 to 23) of the specified date and time. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp          
 && hour >= 6 && hour <= 23 | minutes <= 30 should say 12:30am but it closes at 12am. The same function works && hour >= 6 && hour <= 20 | minutes <= 30 and it closes at exactly at 9:30pm up until 11:30pm. when i try to  input 12:30am it marks close at 12am

Comment: Well, you answered it yourself: 12:30AM is 0:30 of tomorrow or (technically) 24:30 in today's time, but getHours() returns ONLY 0 - 23 so it cannot compare to 24th hour. If you want your opening hours to end tomorrow, you will need to calculate is as tomorrow, not today.

Comment: thats when i get brain fart. Should i mark it down && hour >= 6 && hour <= 23 | minutes <= 30 because if thats what you are refering to it doesn't work after 23. it doesn't read the minutes but before 23 it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say have your Friday's and Saturday's opening hours 6am - 11:30pm which is 06:00 - 23:30. The condition is:

```
((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 6 && (hour < 23 || minutes < 30)
```

If you want to move the closing hour one hour later it would be 6am - 12:30am which would be 06:00 - 24:30 but since a day ends at 23:59 it means 24:30 is actually 0:30 of the next day. For that reason you have to separate the condition into two parts:

```
((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 6) //this checks Friday's and Saturday's opening time
    || ((dayOfWeek == 6 || dayOfWeek == 0) && hour == 0 && minutes < 30) //this checks the closing time on the next day (30 minutes after midnight of Saturday and Sunday)
```

Comment: i get what you mean in separating the hours but 0 = 1 am,  1 =2am. what i end up doing is ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 ) && hour >= 10 && hour == 23 | minutes < 30). i stood last night up until 1 am and the first problem you end up putting ((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 6 && (hour < 23 || minutes < 30) doesnt work after 1 am but i did work the one i did on top. only problam is now i have to wait to check if it closes after 12:30am. i'll use ur second equation if my does not work later after 12am and 1am.

Comment: Well maybe you should start by learning how clock works before you try to write a program. My recommendation is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock . And maybe actually trying what the methods return before saying such nonsense: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime

Comment: i haven't tried your second combo but i will using 23 instead of zero because again 0 is 1am also for your first equation i did not add the () so i'll be adding it....i just notice duh. but ima insert it first with a hour == 23 because it needs to be greater but their isn't any greater number because it only goes between 0-23 and stop at 30 or between 12:30am  but i'll also try yours if mine doesn't work exactly the same. so i'll hit you up in a week.

Comment: ok so i get it now. Thanks a lot but your && hour == 0 && minutes < 30 did not work so i change it to and it worked&& hour == 0 || minutes < 30

Comment: dudesorryfor the inconvenience i'm a noob at programing(not even good in math but primary an artist like paint and drawing ). got into it because this guy i pay to do this website for me dip after taking my money so i decided to learn. but now i get even more ways to write programming i did not know. after im done desiging it i will like to show it to you so if you wanna participate in tweaking it. im going for design and basics first to get traffic then adding the complex functions later as i get better. but it will be cool to have people onboard.basically facebook+google+grubHub = my website